# Errors in this code for volume control Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio

Im trying to get this code to work with buttons in visual basic. Ive looked on the internet and the only solutions I could find for volume controls are all written in C#. I converted this code to Visual Basic. Can someone overlook this code for me?

I was getting errors with me.handle

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace Test
    Public Class Test
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As Integer = &H80000
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP As Integer = &HA0000
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN As Integer = &H90000
        Private Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319
        <DllImport("user32.dll")>
        Public Shared Function SendMessageW(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

        Private Sub Mute()
            SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Me.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
        End Sub

        Private Sub VolDown()
            SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Me.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN, IntPtr))
        End Sub

        Private Sub VolUp()
            SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Me.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP, IntPtr))
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: oops this is visual basic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `Me.Handle` is trying to reference a field or property called `Handle` on the same class (`Test`), but no such field or property exists.

You will need to find a way of obtaining the handle. The approach varies based on whether you are a WinForms or WPF application. If you are a console application, you will need to create a window (even if you don't show it) to participate in Windows Messages (i.e. the `WM_*` values you're using).